# jQuery crossfade images and hide them with display:none

Tags: jquery, css, opacity, fade

I need to fade a div with a background-image to another in the same container with fixed dimension.

FadeIn and Out are what I need and work quite well, because I want the possibility to click on each visible image, and that's impossible working with opacity, even if it's exactly the effect I'd like to have.. a kind of crossfading between the images.

HTML

```
<div class="image_container">
    <div id="image1"></div>
    <div id="image2" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

my simplified js

```
$( this ).click(function() {
  $( "#image1" ).fadeOut();
   $( "#image2" ).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: what do you mean by Crossfade? did you mean if you click on image1, image2 should fadeIn and image1 should fadeOut, and vice-verse on click of image2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing images in an absolute position on top of each other, you can use jQuery to fade between them like this:

```
<div class="image_container">
  <div id="image1"></div>
  <div id="image2" style="display:none"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascrtip">
  $(".image_container").click(function(){
    $(this).find("div").fadeOut();
    $(this).find("div:hidden").fadeIn();
  })
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .image_container div {
    position:absolute;
    width:338px;
    height:225px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }

  #image1 {
    background-image:url(http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg);
  }

  #image2 {
    background-image:url(http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_02.jpg);
  }
</style>
```

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/zmur2v8q/1/

Simply click on the image to fade into the other one.

Comment: I thought about it, but absolute positioning it's actually uncomfortable in some layouts. Any way to do that without absolute?

Comment: You could do a relative position and use negative margins if you know the image sizes.  However, if you place the absolute-positioned div inside of a relative-positioned one, you'll generally be fine with most layouts.  It's hard to give more information without know more about your specific issue.

Comment: It's actually pretty nice, thank you. I found out I had a problem with a CSS transition on the same class, that was working really bad with the jQuery fade